# Python Expected Axis Error, number of elements: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on the following code and I'm running into a problem, I'm not sure how to solve this error. Any help?

,,,

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\AJ\\Downloads\\Data - Data.csv')  
df.head()  #To view first 5 records/rows

#Filter the data frame(df) for STATION, NAME/LOCATION, DATE, AWND, SNOW columns
df1 = df[['STATION', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'AWND', 'SNOW']]

#convert the data frame(df1) to filteredData.csv file
df1.to_csv('filteredData.csv', index=False)

#Already filtered data frame(df1) is there. Using the same for further flow,
import datetime as dt
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)  #convert the DATE column into python standard date format


#Filter the data for 2016 & compute the mean/average of SNOW
average2016 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2016].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].mean()
average2016 = average2016.reset_index()
average2016.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'AVERAGE_SNOW']
average2016.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)


#Filter the data for 2017 & compute the mean/average of SNOW
average2017 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2017].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].mean()
average2017 = average2016.reset_index()
average2017.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'AVERAGE_SNOW']
average2017.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)

#Already filtered data frame(df1) is there. Using the same for further flow,
import datetime as dt
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)  #convert the DATE column into python standard date format

#Filter the data for 2016 & compute the sum of SNOW
total2016 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2016].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].sum()
total2016 = average2016.reset_index()
total2016.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'SUM_SNOW']  #reframing column names
total2016.to_csv('total2016.csv', index=False)  #converting into csv file


#Filter the data for 2017 & compute the sum of SNOW
total2017 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2017].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].sum()
total2017 = average2016.reset_index()
total2017.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'SUM_SNOW']  #reframing column names
total2017.to_csv('total2017.csv', index=False)  #converting into csv file

#Read the average2016.csv file
average2016 = pd.read_csv('average2016.csv')
average2016_sort = average2016.sort_values(by='AVERAGE_SNOW', ascending=False)  #sort the data on descending order
top3_2016 = average2016_sort['NAME'].head(3)

#Read the average2017.csv file
average2017 = pd.read_csv('average2017.csv')
average2017_sort = average2017.sort_values(by='AVERAGE_SNOW', ascending=False)  #sort the data on descending order
top3_2017 = average2017_sort['NAME'].head(3)

#combining both top3_2016 & top3_2017 data frames
top3 = pd.concat((top3_2016,top3_2017), axis=1)
top3.columns = ['2016', '2017']
top3.to_csv('top3.csv', index=False)

# Read the filteredData.csv file
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.read_csv('filteredData.csv')
df3_sort = df3.sort_values(by='AWND', ascending=False)  #sorting the AWND data in descending order
top10AWND = df3_sort.head(10)  #storing top10 AWND values


# convert data frame into top10AWND.csv file
top10AWND.to_csv('top10AWND.csv', index=False)
,,,
```

The error I am getting is as follows:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements

I'm really confused as to why this may be happening, I can't seem to find what this is referring to? Does anyone spot it?

Comment: The error is literal. It says you are trying to assign a 3-element array to a selection that is 4 elements long. Where does the error occur? What do you see when inspecting the items that throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

You just have some typos. Check your code for "FRAMENAME.reset_index()" Sections.

Note: You only need to import a module once.

I have corrected the errors. Try.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\AJ\\Downloads\\Data - Data.csv')  
df.head()  #To view first 5 records/rows

#Filter the data frame(df) for STATION, NAME/LOCATION, DATE, AWND, SNOW columns
df1 = df[['STATION', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'AWND', 'SNOW']]

#convert the data frame(df1) to filteredData.csv file
df1.to_csv('filteredData.csv', index=False)

#Already filtered data frame(df1) is there. Using the same for further flow,
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)  #convert the DATE column into python standard date format

#Filter the data for 2016 & compute the mean/average of SNOW
average2016 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2016].groupby(by=[
    'NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].mean()
average2016 = average2016.reset_index()
average2016.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'AVERAGE_SNOW']
average2016.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)


#Filter the data for 2017 & compute the mean/average of SNOW
average2017 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2017].groupby(by=[
    'NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].mean()
average2017 = average2017.reset_index()
average2017.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'AVERAGE_SNOW']
average2017.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)

#Already filtered data frame(df1) is there. Using the same for further flow,
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)  #convert the DATE column into python standard date format

#Filter the data for 2016 & compute the sum of SNOW
total2016 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2016].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].sum()
total2016 = total2016.reset_index()
total2016.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'SUM_SNOW']  #reframing column names
total2016.to_csv('total2016.csv', index=False)  #converting into csv file


#Filter the data for 2017 & compute the sum of SNOW
total2017 = df1[df1['DATE'].dt.year==2017].groupby(by=['NAME', df1['DATE'].dt.month])['SNOW'].sum()
total2017 = total2017.reset_index()
total2017.columns = ['NAME', 'MONTH', 'SUM_SNOW']  #reframing column names
total2017.to_csv('total2017.csv', index=False)  #converting into csv file

#Read the average2016.csv file
average2016 = pd.read_csv('average2016.csv')
average2016_sort = average2016.sort_values(by=
'AVERAGE_SNOW', ascending=False)  #sort the data on descending order
top3_2016 = average2016_sort['NAME'].head(3)

#Read the average2017.csv file
average2017 = pd.read_csv('average2017.csv')
average2017_sort = average2017.sort_values(by=
'AVERAGE_SNOW', ascending=False)  #sort the data on descending order
top3_2017 = average2017_sort['NAME'].head(3)

#combining both top3_2016 & top3_2017 data frames
top3 = pd.concat((top3_2016,top3_2017), axis=1)
top3.columns = ['2016', '2017']
top3.to_csv('top3.csv', index=False)

# Read the filteredData.csv file
df3 = pd.read_csv('filteredData.csv')
df3_sort = df3.sort_values(by='AWND', ascending=False)  #sorting the AWND data in descending order
top10AWND = df3_sort.head(10)  #storing top10 AWND values

# convert data frame into top10AWND.csv file
top10AWND.to_csv('top10AWND.csv', index=False)
```

You may want to read this as well : [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)